Predictive Margin never gives negative values
I am using Jupyter Notebook to do a Random Forest Classification model. After the model is finished, I want it to calculate and print the Prediciton Margins, which it does, but no instance has a negative Prediction Margin.
I used the following line:
margins_new_data = np.max(proba_values, axis=1) - np.partition(proba_values, -2, axis=1)[:, -2]
Conceptually, I understand the Prediction Margin as a number between 1 and -1 that helps to identify how confident the model is at predicting a specific instance (With 1 being totally confident and -1 being totally non-confident).
Am I applying a wrong line or am I misunderstanding the concept?
